# Conditional mapping of an array

Tags: javascript, angular

On my photo gallery app, I am trying to map a array of images on the condition that the image album name matches the album name the user selects to view. As all the images on the images array are currently assigned to the album 'Cambodia' this works correctly when selecting the album Cambodia (I have logged the new mapped array to the console and it logs all the images correctly).

The issue I am having is that when selecting a different album such as 'Laos' (which currently there are no images in the 'images' array with that album name), then an array of all the images is still logged to the console but all with an undefined value.

I'm struggling to understand why there isn't an empty array logged to the console and this was the expected behavior?

Here's the album-view component:

```
export class AlbumViewComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private albumsService: AlbumsService, private galleryListService: GalleryListService) { }

  selectedAlbum: Album;

  albumImageArr: Image[];

  images: Image[];

  ngOnInit() {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.params['id']; 

    this.selectedAlbum = this.albumsService.getAlbum(id); // THIS GETS THE ALBUM THE USER HAS SELECTED BASED ON THE ID PARAMETER IN THE URL

    this.images = this.galleryListService.getImages(); // THE IMAGES ARE RETRIEVED FROM A SEPARATE SERVICE FILE

    this.albumImageArr = this.images.map(e => {
      if(e.album === this.selectedAlbum.name) {
        return e;
      } 
    });

    console.log(this.albumImageArr);


  }

}
```

This is the console log for the albumImageArr when the user selects the album 'Cambodia':

```
(18) [Image, Image, Image, Image, Image, Image, Image, Image, Image, Image, Image, Image, Image, Image, Image, Image, Image, Image]
```

So as you can see above, this works correctly as it is logging an array of Image objects when the album name matches the selected album name.

This is the console log for the albumImageArr when the user selects any other album:

```
(18) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

---Edit---

As requested by Michael D below, here is the gallery-list service file:

```
import { Image } from '../shared/image.model';

export class GalleryListService {

    private images = [
        new Image('Man Praying', 1, 'Cambodia', 'Man praying to Sun', '£100', '../../assets/Images/Cambodia/Praying to the Sun.JPG', '250px', '330px'),
        new Image('Man Praying', 2, 'Cambodia', 'Man praying to Sun', '£100', '../../assets/Images/Cambodia/Praying to the Sun.JPG', '275px', '330px'),
        new Image('Man Praying', 3, 'Cambodia', 'Man praying to Sun', '£100', '../../assets/Images/Cambodia/Praying to the Sun.JPG', '300px', '330px'),
        new Image('Man Praying', 4, 'Cambodia', 'Man praying to Sun', '£100', '../../assets/Images/Cambodia/Praying to the Sun.JPG', '275px', '330px'),

]

getImages() {
        return this.images;
    }
```

This is the Image.model file:

```
export class Image {

    constructor(
        public name: string,
        public id: number,
        public album: string,
        public description: string,
        public price: any,
        public imagePath: string,
        public heightSize: any,
        public widthSize: any) {}
}
```

Comment: Could you please show how `this.galleryListService.getImages()` is implemented?

Comment: yeah sure give me a sec

Comment: this code is not sound or correct. Map is a one to one function. There is absolutely no such thing as conditional mapping. That breaks the functoriality of lists. You should use .filter here. If you also need to map you can compose filter with map. Map keeps the one to one nature, thus you getting undefined

Comment: Ok thanks I'll look into this. Yes it does, it changes to albums/1 for example (1 being the id of the album being selected)

Comment: On second thought using map is the issue. Edited the comment . It tries to keep the one to one nature

Comment: Awesome thanks! Just simply changed map to filter. Add it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct answer.

Comment: happy to help! answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` is a one-to-one function. Meaning it will map every element in the original list to a new element in the new list. It can not modify the length of the list. In your function, you are not telling it how to map the elements that doesn't satisfy the predicates so JS maps them to `undefined`

A catamorphism such as filter on the other hand can do this.

```
this.albumImageArr = this.images.filter(e => e.album === this.selectedAlbum.name);
```